# Highlighting specific part of python command line

Tags: python, command-line, highlight

I'm using Python 3.3... When executing script in command line, there are some parts that I want to be highlighted. I need highlighted specific parts of specific lines, e.g. chars 5 through 19 of line 25 (something like that).
I found curses module in documentation, but I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python33\proj\proj16\logdisp.py", line 14, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Programs\Python33\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: No module named '_curses'
```

I'm guessing the module curses was removed (or I'm doing something wrong...)
I also tried pygments, but I failed to install it. Does it work with Python 3.3?

Anyway, how to do highlighting with Python 3.3?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? In that case see [this](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) because you don't have curses for windows.

Comment: Yes. I'm on Windows. If it's working with Python 3.3, it would help me a lot, but it's pretty outdated... It's last update was in 2000. Are you sure it's compatible? No modules I tried so far that were intended for Python 2 worked on Python 3...

Comment: I got the info from [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html). The other posibility is to do something yourself if you don't find something in the docs. I worked with Unix in the old days and I had to edit the curses configuration then.